# Numbers change after reading Pickle data (python) into R

Tags: python, r, pickle, reticulate

I have a large dataset with unix epoch dates embedded in lists/dicts currently stored as a pickle file. I tried to import the pickle file into R using the reticulate package vis py_load_object() function. Other than, the unix epoch dates (in milliseconds), all else seems fine.

I get very strange integer conversions. For example, epoch date of 694137600000 is read as -1647101952 in R. I was wondering if there is an explanation and a work-around.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be overflowing the maximum safe integer?

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to help you without a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) but here are some ideas:

- You can un-pickle and convert the file to `pandas` data frame inside
  your Python script. The `source_python` function from `reticulate`
  will import it as an R data frame. Please refer to the documentation
  for additional information on type conversions:
  [rstudio/reticulate](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate)
- It is always possible to un-pickle the file and export as a common
  format such as `csv` using Python and then import it into R. This
  way, you can bypass `reticulate`, which is not always an
  efficient option.

Please also note that you may need some help when it comes to handle 13-digit numbers in R. The package `bit64` would be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the values are being treated as 32 bit integers by reticulate - you can see the problem with the python snippet below:

```
In [1]: v = 694137600000

In [2]: v.bit_length()
Out[2]: 40

In [3]: import ctypes

In [4]: ctypes.c_int(v)
Out[4]: c_long(-1647101952)

In [5]: _.value
Out[5]: -1647101952

In [6]: ctypes.c_int64(v)
Out[6]: c_longlong(694137600000)

In [7]: ctypes.c_int32(v)
Out[7]: c_long(-1647101952)
```

One of the easiest workarounds is to, in python, unpickle your file and save as a .csv file but you should find that if you convert the pickled data to a pandas data frame and then access it from R it will be converted to an R dataframe - unless the date/time is the first column, *(see [here](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/calling_python.html#data-frames) for why).*